# Accessing counter outside while loop java

Tags: java, while-loop, counter

The error that I'm getting is division by 0.

I'ts due to the value of `totDrivers`. I'm not sure if it's because the counter isn't updating as the `while` loop cycles through. Or if it's because `totDrivers` I'm improperly accessing the variable from outside the loop.

Other posts I've read said to access a variable outside a loop you need to initialize it outside the loop.But it doesn't state if by doing this, a counters updated value will come out.

```
[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at Statistics.main(Statistics.java:84)]
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Statistics
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        //counters initilization
        int f=0; //female
        int m=0;//male
        int u=0;//unspecified
        int u25=0;//less than 25 in age
        int mu=0;//male and under 25
        int bt=0;//between 25 and 75
        int ab=0;//above 75 
        int y=0;//res
        int n=0;//non res

        int age=0;
        String gender="U";
        String nlRes="Y";
        int totDrivers=0;

        while (age !=0)
        {

            totDrivers++;
            System.out.print("Please enter age\\(Enter 0 if theres no more input\\): ");
            age= in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please enter gender(M,F,or U): ");
            gender= in.next();
            System.out.print("Please enter gender: ");
            nlRes= in.next();       


            if (age<25)
            {
                u25++;
            }
            if(gender.equals("M"))
            {
                mu++;
            } 
            else if(age>=25&&age<=75)
            {
                bt++;
            }
            else if(age>75)
            {
                ab++;
            }


            if(gender.equals("M"))
            {
                m++;
            }
            else if(gender.equals("F"))
            {
                f++;
            }
            else if(gender.equals("U"))
            {
                u++;
            }


            if(nlRes.equals("Y"))
            {
                y++;
            }
            else if(nlRes.equals("N"))
            {
                n++;
            }
            System.out.println("totd"+totDrivers);
        }
        //output

        double perU25=(u25/totDrivers)*100;
        double perMU25=(mu/m)*100;
        double perF=(f/totDrivers)*100;
        double perNonNL=(n/totDrivers)*100;
        double perAbove=(ab/totDrivers)*100;

        System.out.println("The % of drivers under 25 is : %"+perU25);
        System.out.println("The % of male drivers under 25 is : %"+perMU25);
        System.out.println("The % of female drives is : %"+perF);
        System.out.println("The % of out of province drivers is : %"+perNonNL);
        System.out.println("The % of drivers over the age of 75 is : %"+perAbove);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is failing? I don't think line 84 is dividing by `totDrivers`.

Comment: A simple `if(totDrivers > 0 && m > 0) { // do your math here }` will fix your problem.  Have you thought that maybe the code never enters your loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your counter = 0 before you do your division

```
if(m != 0)
{
double perMU25=(mu/m)*100;
}
```

Comment: if thats done, then in then theres a error saying it can't find the variable which is because it dont enter the loop. That means totDrivers isnt updating and i cant figure out why

Comment: It's because you have age set to 0 and your loop executes when age != 0